# Using abstraction and interface on the same Object without having to cast it

Tags: java, interface, abstract, abstraction

I would like to use abstraction(from a mother class) and an interface on the same Object without having to cast it.

I've already search about it and it seems that casting is a common method for that kind of purpose.

I have got a program where `Dog` extends `Animal` implements `Friendly`

Animal let the dog `yell()` and Friendly (Interface) let him `hug()`
Before using Friendly(Interface), I used to do it :

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
dog.yell();
```

but now, to add the interface, I have to cast the dog into a Friendly type like that so that he can hug() :

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
dog.yell();
((Friendly) dog).hug();
```

Is there any better way to do this as my teacher told me that casting was usually a bad idea.

Comment: If you could do it without casting, why do you think people use casting? Casting *is* a bad idea, but if you only have a reference to an `Animal`, that's all you can do. You can only do it without casting if you have a reference to a `Friendly`, or to something which implements `Friendly` like `Dog`.

Comment: You said Friendly is a interface with hug method and where is the hug method is implemented?

Comment: @Andy Turner That's why I'm asking it, abstraction was here to not have to use casting and now I find myself with the obligation of using casting if I want to add an interface.

Comment: @Sand hug() method is implemented in the Dog class (as Dog implements Friendly interface)

Comment: Maybe Animal implements Friendly? Otherwise I don't see another way without casting

Comment: Solution depends on limitations you are able to accept. For instance you could create generic method `<T extends Animal & Friendly> method(T t){t.yell(); t.hug();}` and use it like `method(new Dog());` but this way you can access to Dog only from withing the method (unless method will return it or internally call other method to which it will pass it as argument).

Comment: @Sand Yes but not all the animals can be friendly. (For example if I add a Wolf class extends Animal, then It would let me write something like wolf.hug() which shouldn't be possible). Seems like that there is no other way than casting for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to avoid casting, then you have to use `Dog` as the type of your `dog` variable:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.yell();
dog.hug();
```

With this, though, you aren't programming to the `Friendly` and `Animal` interfaces, which you should ideally do when abstraction is used correctly.
**If you must** declare `dog` as `Animal` or as `Friendly` in code just like this, then you're using abstraction for the wrong reasons.

> ...my teacher told me that casting was usually a bad idea.

Casting is something no one likes doing, but everyone has to do it when it's necessary.

Comment: Can I do something like : `Animal<Friendly> dog = new Dog<>();` ? Since yesterday I'm looking into Generics Class and I wonder if It could be the solution to my problem ?

Comment: @ThomasCloarec No. Generics aren't designed to solve that problem.